# How to write Unit test in angular for testing routing code inside subscribe block

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am new to unit testing in jasmine and karma for angular, here I am trying to test the router navigation, here we have a service to which some data is sent and inside the subscribe block I am navigating to a link,

For this how can I write a unit test.

CODE FOR THE FUNCTION INSIDE TS FILE.

```
onAction(action) {
   
    if (action == true) {
        this.data.action = action;
        this.data.loggedInId = this.id;
        this.Formservice.formMethod(this.data).subscribe(() => {
        this.router.navigate([`/${this.breadCrum}`]);
    });
    }
   }
```

CODE FOR THE SPEC.TS FILE

```
it("Check the router navigate after onAction",fakeAsync(()=> {        
        component.onAction(true)
        flushMicrotasks()
        tick(10)
        fixture.detectChanges()
        tick(10)
        expect (mockRouter.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith ('/action-taken');
    }));
```

STEPS I FOLLOWED TO CREATE MOCK ROUTER SERVICE

```
import { Routes, RouterModule, ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

let mockRouter = {
    navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')
  }

providers:[
{ provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter}
]
```

Here am I getting the error of **Cannot read property of 'subscribe' of undefined**

Comment: you should write a mock for the `FormService` as well to handle the subscribe on the `formMethod`

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 mocks:

1. For service:

```
export class MockFormservice{
   formMethod(){
     return of({})
   }
}
```

2. For Router:

```
export class MockRouter{
   navigate(){}
}
```

In this way you can reuse it in other components, and then in `spec` file:

```
providers:[
   { provide: Formservice, useClass: MockFormservice},
   { provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter}
]
```

you can also `jasmine.createSpy` to keep the router mock code short. Your choice.

I would strongly recommend you to read my [article on how to handle such cases](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49). Its small yet focused on daily use testing for a developer. There is a series of [articles which has covered few more scenarios which will surely help you get comfortable](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7) in fundamentals in testing angular code. Do let me know if you need more help